# Neural Networks InvalidArgumentError w/ keras, tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to design a predictive model for a thermal powerplant emissions based on the energy generated and coal properties. I watched different tutorials to design this code as this is not my expertise area but I'm failling everytime I run the model cell. 
**Here's the code for standardize and preprocess the data**:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
raw_data=np.loadtxt('raw_data.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
unscaled_inputs=raw_data[:,0:30]
targets=raw_data[:,30:110]
scaled_inputs = preprocessing.scale(unscaled_inputs)
samples_count=scaled_inputs.shape[0]
train_samples_count=int(0.8*samples_count)
validation_samples_count=int(0.1*samples_count)
test_samples_count=samples_count-train_samples_count-validation_samples_count
train_inputs=scaled_inputs[:train_samples_count]
train_targets=targets[:train_samples_count]
       validation_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]       validation_targets=targets[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]

test_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]
test_targets=targets[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]

np.savez('coal_data_train', inputs=train_inputs, targets=train_targets)
np.savez('coal_data_validation', inputs=validation_inputs, targets=validation_targets)
np.savez('coal_data_test', inputs=test_inputs, targets=test_targets)
```

**Here's the code used for the model**:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
npz=np.load('coal_data_train.npz')
train_inputs = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float)
train_targets = npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_validation.npz')
validation_inputs, validation_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_test.npz')
test_inputs, test_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)
input_size = 30
output_size = 81
hidden_layer_size = 61
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear') 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 10
max_epochs = 50
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)

model.fit(train_inputs, 
          train_targets, 
          batch_size=10, 
          epochs=max_epochs, 
          verbose=2,
          callbacks=[early_stopping], 
          validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets),
          )
```

**It returns the error**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTil.png)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share the dataset statistics? How many records are there in validation_inputs, validation_targets?

Comment: There is a mismatch in `targets` you are providing to the model (which is 80) and the `output_size` you are expecting from the model prediction (which is 81). Check your `output_size`. Update `targets=raw_data[:,30:110]` to `targets=raw_data[:,30:111]` If you want `output_size` as 81.

Answer (score 0):

Your output size is bigger than it should be. Try:

```
output_size = 80
```

Comment: Thank you, I was misunderstanding elements counting. Anyway, my metrics was also wrong.